# Teleric MVC and knockout update values inside

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, telerik-mvc

I would like to use Teleric MVC components and knockout.
I found good example how to use it http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/compatibility-with-knockout.aspx

But i have a littel bit other task, when I change some value of knockout object inside of java-script function, teleric contol get this value but don't re-drow UI values. Teleric show new value just if user click on control. Does any one have any idea how to update teleric controls in my case ?

```
  //Show selected information
    function ShowKioskSettings(newDataFromAjaxcall) {
        //general
        viewModel.Somevalue = newDataFromAjaxcall.Somevalue;

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I findout solution, calling $("input:text").focus(); in the end of function. but any way it looks like Telerik issue.